# Can a python dictionary be partially a reference to another dictionary and partially a copy?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

If I define dictionaries like this:

```py
d1 = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
d2 = d1
```

then `d2` is a reference to `d1` and if I modify `d2` then `d1` is also modified:

```py
d2['b'] = [5, 6]
print(d1)         # {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [5, 6]}
```

If instead I copy `d1`, then changes to `d2` don't affect `d1`:

```py
d1 = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
d2 = d1.copy()
d2['b'] = [5, 6]
print(d1)         # {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

**Question**

Can I have `d2` be partially a reference (say in `a`) and partially a copy (in `b`) of `d1`, so that I can do something like:

```py
d1 = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
d2 = ???
d2['a'] = [5, 6]
d2['b'] = [7, 8]
print(d1)         # {'a': [5, 6], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: Not literally, no. You would need to have the value of the `a` key in both dictionaries to be a reference to a mutable object that you stick in both dictionaries, then mutate later.

Comment: No; `d2` is either a copy of `d1` or it isn't. There's no middle ground.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Also, it's more accurate to say that `d1` and `d2` are both references to the same `dict`; there is no real sense in which `d1` is the "real" reference and `d2` the "new" one or a reference to the *name* `d1`.

Comment: @oskros In my actual problem `a`  is very large and will never be modified, and I want to share memory for `d1['a']` and `d2['a']` and save the time needed to copy it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you're right, that's what I want: `a` refers to the same mutable object in d1 and d2, and `b` refers to a different mutable object for each dictionary.

Comment: @user175348 You need to handle that manually then. Python does not supply a way of managing that for you. Create the object outside of the dictionary, then manually add it to both.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How do I do that? I tried `d2 = {}; d2['a'] = d1['a']; d2['b'] = d1['b'].copy()` and it doesn't work (both a and b behave as copies).

Comment: @user175348 `mut = [3, 4]; d1['a'] = mut; d2['a'] = mut; mut[0] = 5; mut[1] = 6;`

Comment: Although I should note that the initial values of `mut` are just for show. They're replaced as soon as the last two statements run.

Answer (score 1):

may your dreams become reality.

```
class newdict(dict):
 def __init__(self,d,partially_a_reference_in=[]):
     self.update(d)
     self.partially_a_reference_in=partially_a_reference_in
     self.setitem=dict.__setitem__
 def __setitem__(self,x,i):
     if  x in self.partially_a_reference_in:
         self.setitem(self,x,i)
         #self.clear()
d1 = newdict({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]},partially_a_reference_in=["a"])
d2=d1         
print(d2)
d2['a'] = [5, 6]
d2['b'] = [7, 8]
print(d1)
```

Comment: My dreams remain dreams... here the assignment to d2['b'] has no effect on d1, but also no effect on d2 itself!

Comment: d2['b'] = [7, 8]
print(d1)         # {'a': [5, 6], 'b': [3, 4]} # this output of d1 mean that [7,8] didn t have effect to d1

Comment: Yes, but it also has no effect on d2, when it _should_ change d2.